# Removing lines in files with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

> Hi, I have an issue replacing a specific line (with an empty line) in
> several files using sed. I guess cause the string I want to replace
> contains the character '>' or '<'because if I remove it, it works
> fine. I want to replace the string  with
> an empty line
>
> This is what I wrote (it doesn't work):

```
sed -i 's/<field outputName="location">//g'
```

Thanks to everyone that suggest a solution.

Comment: `sed -i 's/.*<field outputName="location">.*//' file`?

Comment: Thanks  @Wiktor Stribiżew
it worked but in this form  sed -i 's/.*<field outputName="location".*>//'

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```bash
sed -i '/<field outputName="location".*>/s/.*//' file
```

Here,

- `/<field outputName="location".*>/` - finds lines that contain `<field outputName="location"`, then any text and then a `>` char
- `s/.*//` - replaces the whole line found with an empty string.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/UdgfRc):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='Text start
... <field outputName="location"> ...
End of text.'
sed '/<field outputName="location".*>/s/.*//' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Text start

End of text.
```